# Round a numpy array to .5 or .0 only

Tags: python, numpy, rounding

I have to round every element inside a numpy array only to .5 or .0 values. I know the `np.arange()` method, however it is not useful in this specific task since I can only use it to set a precision equal to one.

Here there is an example of what I should do:

```
x = np.array([2.99845, 4.51845, 0.33365, 0.22501, 2.48523])
x_rounded = some_function(x)

>>> x_rounded
array([3.0, 4.5, 0.5, 0.0, 2.5])
```

Is there a built-in method to do so or I have to create it?
If I should create that method, is there an efficient? I'm working on a big dataset, so I would like to avoid iterating over each element.

Comment: It would be *impossible* to do this without "iterating over each element"; the iteration may be buried inside of some other method, but it will be there.

Comment: @ScottHunter Well I guess it is clear that OP meant a solution without an explicit for-loop, but with the power of vectorization.

Comment: @user3389669: "guess it is clear" == "not clear at all"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([2.99845, 4.51845, 0.33365, 0.22501, 2.48523])
np.round(2 * x) / 2
```

Output:

```py
array([3. , 4.5, 0.5, 0. , 2.5])
```